# Debian apt-get update not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, java

I have setup multiple servers prior with no issues, however after running **apt-get update** I see this after a long delay:

```
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/packages/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Could not connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:80 (213.133.99.97). - connect (110: Connection timed out)
```

Running Debian Wheezy x64. And am unable to install java because of this. What can I do to troublshoot or find the issue?

Comment: Download the file manually, through a broswer, it's possiblenthe source of the package is simply down

Comment: Can you ping the server name or IP? Inbound port blocked on your network? Company firewall? (And what Ramhound said!)

Comment: I will try what ramhound said